# The method call(Activity) in the type <type> is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){})

Tags: android

Groping in the dark... This time I am receiving the following error in Eclipse:

> The method call(Activity) in the type
>   IntentsUtils is not applicable for the
>   arguments (new
>   View.OnClickListener(){})

This error refers to the call() line in a callback hooked up to a button, in a class that extends Activity:

```
public class UnderstandingIntents extends Activity {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    // A call-back for when the user presses the testintents button.
    OnClickListener mTestIntentsListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        IntentsUtils.call(this);
        }
    };
}
```

IntentsUtils is a class copied verbatim from [listing 3-33 here](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4529).

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to reference the Activity Class (UnderstandingIntents) in an Anonymous inner class, hence when you say "this" it refers to View.OnClickListener(){}

to correct this do the following code:

```
IntentsUtils.call(UnderstandingIntents.this);
```

This way, your Activity class gets referenced.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by the steep learning curve coming from C++. It's not only the Android API, terminology and new concepts. It's things like "Anonymous inner class" of which I wasn't aware (until now). All answers where basically identical, but yours was by far the most educating. ++1. Thanks!

Comment: For future generations of clueless newbies like myself, here is an intro to "anonymous inner class" (isn't "inner class" implying anonymous?) http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/anonymous_innerclassestutorial.shtml

Comment: Good article! To answer your question, an inner class doesn't necessarily imply it is anonymous. It is anonymous to classes outside of the outer class (Java file) it is contained in. By syntax, an Anonymous inner class does not use the keywords class, implements or extends (as demonstrated by your question). Its nature is such that it is a class that is created only within a method. An Inner class however uses these keywords to make a class that is independent to a method. A great example can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: +1 again for this great clarification. Note to myself: The anonymous class in my original post is the one enclose between {} right after 'new OnClickListener()'. I still have to figure out what 'new OnClickListener()' means. :)

Comment: According to the Android API of OnClickListener( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) it is an interface with an abstract method (a method which must be defined when instantiated), which in this case is OnClick, that will perform the procedures that you define in OnClick once you click the item that the listener is defined for. Therefore an OnClickListener listens for the user to click the item, and captures the click, routing it to the procedures that are defined in OnClick

Answer (score 2):

The `this` parameter passed into `IntentsUtils.call()` refers to the object within which it is being used, in this case an instance of `OnClickListener`. Try replacing the `this` parameter with `UnderstandingIntents.this`:

```
IntentsUtils.call(UnderstandingIntents.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
IntentsUtils.call(UnderstandingIntents.this);
```